# How you do you disable ListView and scrolling for ListView programatically

Tags: android, listview

I want to disable `Listview`  and `scroll` for `ListView` programmatically.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I want after disable the ListView , onclick of disabled ListView it should work differently. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

whatever be the control just disable it in your case

```
listView.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: after disable the ListView I want after onclick of disabled listview it should work differently. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using this code u can disable both things in listview  `enableDisableView(listview , false);`

```
public void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
        view.setEnabled(enabled);

        if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

            for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
                enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```